# Option to boot Ubuntu is occasionally missing from the BIOS boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, grub2, uefi

I recently installed Ubuntu as my first distro. Everything has been going smoothly until now.

Usually when I start my system I press the power button on my laptop.  After seeing the Dell logo, I press <kbd>F2</kbd> to get into the BIOS options menu. Then I select Ubuntu from the boot options in order to start Ubuntu,

Recently I have been getting a problem with my boot. After I press the power button and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to access the BIOS settings, I don't see the Ubuntu option in the BIOS. I have to restart the laptop and then the Ubuntu option is there on the third boot.

Normally this is what I see:

[image: picture of a screen showing a boot priority screen in a BIOS options menu with Ubuntu as one of the options]

During a problem boot UEFI BOOT and its options are missing from the boot priority screen. This is what I see:

[image: picture of a screen showing a boot priority screen in a BIOS options menu. Ubuntu is not an option.]

Comment: Is there a reason that you are manually choosing Ubuntu on every boot? This doesn't appear to be a dual-boot config. Can you think of any reasons this might be happening? Have you had any other intermittent problems with drives or partitions? Have you made changes to partitions recently? @karel - I apologize your edit was overwritten -- we must have had the same idea as it looks like we both submitted edits within a few seconds of each other - didn't even know that was possible!

Comment: @Nmath There was no problem this time because I hadn't finished editing this question anyway.

Comment: You show Ubuntu as an UEFI boot entry, but system set to Legacy boot? If Ubuntu is UEFI, you should have UEFI on, CSM/Legacy/BIOS setting off. Only if installed with UEFI Secure boot on, should then you turn on Secure boot. Dell normally uses f2 for UEFI settings and f12 for UEFI boot menu. If you update UEFI, it may revert to defaults & you have to redo settings including AHCI, Secure boot off, fast boot off & maybe others.